# How to tag Strixhaven questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e

So, the D&D 5e adventure book/campaign setting *Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos* is coming out December 7, and we're likely to be getting a few questions about it afterwards. It's a book about playing a D&D campaign as students at the magical university named Strixhaven, on the world of Arcavios, and which was also the setting of the Magic the Gathering set *Strixhaven*.

How should these questions be tagged?

- The name of the book, [strixhaven-a-curriculum-of-chaos](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strixhaven-a-curriculum-of-chaos)?
- The name of the world, [arcavios](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcavios)?
- The name that seems to given to the product line in its branding,
  [strixhaven](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strixhaven)?
- Some combination of these things, in case additional products set on
  the world of Arcavios are released in the future, or to allow
  distinctions between questions about the contents of the book (e.g.
  feats, spells, monster stat-blocks, etc.) and questions about the
  lore of the setting?

Answer (score 11):

#### For now, tag them like we do questions about the other MtG D&D settings: [theros](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theros) and [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica).

Ravnica and Theros questions seem to be tagged appropriately, maybe those tags are underutilized, maybe they aren’t. There are plenty of questions about content from those setting books without the setting tags, but it seems those questions don’t actually have much to do about the setting itself. This seems like okay practice to me.

So tagging questions where the setting is in view with [strixhaven](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strixhaven) should be just fine, and is consistent with how we have handled the other MtG settings. We can reevaluate our tagging when additional content is released in the future.

---

I do want to go ahead and do the work to document in detail the current tagging practice for [theros](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theros) and [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica), since I said “do it like we already do”, and because I imagine we will see similar patterns emerge with Strixhaven.

##### Theros

We currently have five questions tagged [theros](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theros):

- One is about comparing the Theros Satyr playable race to a Satyr race from a 3rd party setting.
- One is about aligning a warlock patron with the Theros Deities.
- Three are about the Piety system introduce in *Mythic Odysseys of Theros*.

This third bullet has a practical parallel in the [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica) questions, more on that in a minute. We have [eleven questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=theros+is%3Aquestion+-%5Btheros%5D) mentioning Theros that don't have the tag. Notably, five of them are about races included in *Mythic Odysseys*, and three of them concern magic items published in *Mythic Odysseys*. The lack of the [theros](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theros) tag here is appropriate: these questions deal with content from the book, but don't concern the setting in any meaningful way.

##### Ravnica

We currently have seven question tagged [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica):

- Two are setting questions
- One concerns the function of a couple of setting specific creatures. (This one would probably be fine without the [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica) tag)
- Four concern the Guild system introduced in *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*.

This third bullet is the practical parallel to the Piety system of *Mythic Odysseys*. Both of these books introduced significant mechanical structures for engaging with a character's backstory. *Strixhaven* seems positioned to include a similar system with its modeling of the collegiate experience<sup>1</sup>:

> Through the book’s multiyear campaign, players begin as first-year students who study, socialize, and adventure their way to graduation.
>
> -From the [product page](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/strixhaven-curriculum-chaos) of *Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos*

Just as Theros and Ravnica questions about the setting specific mechanics (Piety and Guilds) are tagged with the setting tags, we will likely see similar practice develop naturally as questions are posted.

Moving on, we have [41 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=ravnica+-%5Bravnica%5D+is%3Aquestion) mentioning Ravnica without the tag, and skimming over them, they all appear to not actually be about the setting or the Guild system, but concern or mention content from the book that isn't really about the setting itself.

---

##### Conclusion

Overall, our tagging habits for [theros](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theros) and [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica) seem consistent with one another even though we never talked about it, and so I imagine similar habits will arise naturally as we engage with the new Strixhaven content.

---

<sup>1</sup> It did.

Comment: And just so readers know, part of "reevaluate our tagging" can easily be "people keep tagging it `arcavios`, so we should make `arcavios` a tag-synonym pointing to `strixhaven`."

Comment: @nitsua or vice versa?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage right, we *could* point everything toward `arcavios`, but the consensus here seems to be that `strixhaven` is the better tag to prioritize.

Comment: I have taken the first step and [posted](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193480/41674) the first [tag:strixhaven] question.

Comment: @TobiasF. I’ve removed the strixhaven tag since the question is about a spell that happens to be from the book, but doesn’t have anything else to do with the setting.

Answer (score 11):

In analogy to the existing [forgotten-realms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forgotten-realms), [ravnica](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ravnica) and [eberron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eberron) tags, we should use the branding [strixhaven](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strixhaven), not the book name nor the World.

Comment: So much this answer as our "what should the tag look like" solution. 